# How to query different categories on index?

Tags: query

I'm new to WP and I want to know how can I show latest posts on different categories separately in blog index ? one section for latest post on Fashion category, one on Health posts, etc.

I know about how to query from DB and that's not the case.

My question specifically is about how can I "plan" to show them. Because I don't know how many categories my theme's user may have. One person can have 3 categories and other one has 6 categories...

p.s: Sorry for my bad English. If the question isn't clear, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You could get the categories and for each of them, you use the [list category posts plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/) shortcode to echo the relevant posts into a div:

```
     $categories = get_categories(); 
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<div>';
        $cat=$category->cat_name;
        echo do_shortcode( '[catlist id='.$cat.' numberposts=5 ]');
        echo '</div>';
     }
```

This goes in the 'latest posts' part of your blog index. Then you can style each div to fit your theme's layout (floated left, min-width)

Without making use of any plugin you could change the code this way:

```
     $categories = get_categories(); 
      foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<div>';
        $cat=$category->cat_name;
        $args=array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'category_name' => $cat,
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
          'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
                echo '<h1><a href='.the_permalink().'>'.the_title().'</a></h1>';
            endwhile;
        } //endif
        wp_reset_postdata();
        echo '</div>';
     } //foreach
```

Comment: Thank you Infrcl. Excellent plugin. But is there any way to achieve the same result WITHOUT using any plugin?

Comment: Never ever use `query_posts`. Rather use `WP_Query`

Comment: Of course. Edited.